# How to create periodical timer with Elixir?

Tags: timer, elixir

I'm trying to create a periodical timer with Elixir which would take the lenght of period (milliseconds) as parameter and a function to be executed after time has elapsed. User should also have option to cancel timer. If passed function returns `:cancel` value, then it should also cancel timer. Here is my code:

```
def start_timer(period, callback_function) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
    timer = Process.send_after(self(), :work, period)
    {:ok, %{timer: timer}}
  end
def handle_info(:work, period) do
    IO.puts("This should printed after every period")
    # Start the timer again
    timer = Process.send_after(self(), :work, period)

    {:noreply, %{timer: timer}}
  end
```

I have not yet implemented cancel-feature or the execution of parameter function as the above doesn't work yet. How I should do this? Any advise is very highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are using your `callback_function` anywhere. If you want that to be available throughout the running of your timer, you will need to pass it along in the state in the 2nd argument to `GenServer.start_link/3`, e.g.

```
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{callback_function: callback_function}, name: __MODULE__)
```

Here is some code that periodically executes a function:

```
defmodule Cronlike do
  use GenServer

  @allowed_units [:second, :minute, :hour, :day]

  def start_link(state) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(%{interval: interval, unit: unit} = state) when is_integer(interval) and interval > 0 and unit in  @allowed_units do
    # wait, bang:
    Process.send_after(self(), :tick, to_ms(interval, unit))
    # bang, wait:
    # send(self(), :tick, to_ms(interval, unit))

    {:ok, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info(:tick, %{interval: interval, unit: unit, 
    callback_function: callback_function} = state) do

    case callback_function.() do
      :cancel -> send(self(), :quit)
      _ -> nil
    end

    Process.send_after(self(), :tick, to_ms(interval, unit))
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:quit, state) do
    {:stop, :normal, state}
  end

  defp to_ms(interval, :second), do: interval * 1000
  defp to_ms(interval, :minute), do: to_ms(interval, :second) * 60
  defp to_ms(interval, :hour), do: to_ms(interval, :minute) * 60
  defp to_ms(interval, :day), do: to_ms(interval, :hour) * 24
end
```

This was adapted from a related article I wrote [Wait, Bang vs. Bang, Wait: Subtleties in Elixir Cron Scripts](https://fireproofsocks.medium.com/wait-bang-vs-bang-wait-subtleties-in-elixir-cron-scripts-6fa7d545ecf6)

Comment: Simply perfection, thank you! Your article was also good, everyone confronting this same problem should read it.